# Call to a member function store() on null Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

When I click on save to update the data on my edit page, I get the following error.

> call to a member function store() on null

```
public function update(User $user)
{
    $this->authorize('update', $user->profile);
    
    $data = request()->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'url' => 'url',
        'image' => '',
    ]);
    
    $imagePath = request('image')
        ->store('profile', 'public');
    $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))
        ->fit(1000, 1000);
    $image->save();
    
    dd($data);
    
    auth()->user->profile->update(array_merge(
        ['image' => $imagePath]
    ));
    
    return redirect("/profile/{$user->id}");
}
```

Comment: `request('image')` is `null`. Is there something unclear about that? How are you uploading this image? Do you have the correct `name="image"` on your input? Did you add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<form>` element? Is this an AJAX request? Please try to provide more information. An error with the associated code is good, but you're missing about half the puzzle here (the entire front-end logic for this Image upload). [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70059943/edit) to include that, otherwise no one can help you without having to guess.

Comment: In addition to the above comment, I thought it'd be `request()->file('image')->store`.. (but `request('image')` might work as well if it hadnt been null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result of $request->file('file') is returning null, and you are trying to call a method on null, resulting in the exception.

Due to the way Laravel handles PUT and PATCH requests, you will need to send your request in a POST request, and supply _method with the value PUT in the header. This is what Laravel expects.

```
'image' => 'required'
```